# Problema al guardar imagenes Laravel 10 .tmp

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema al intentar guardar la ruta de la imagen que subo en la base de datos, la imagen si se almacena bien en la carpeta storage, pero la URL en la base de datos no, lo que almacena es una ruta temporal: C:\xampp\tmp\php5399.tmp. Les agradesco de antemano su ayuda.

Esta es la ruta que aparece en el codigo fuente: <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/C:\xampp\tmp\phpA485.tmp".

Mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Book::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->route('books.create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $book = new Book();

    $book->title = $request->title;
    $book->status = 1;
    $user = auth()->user();
    $book->owner_id = $user->id;

    if ($request->hasFile('image_path')) {
        $imagePath = $request->file('image_path');
        $imageName = Str::slug($request->title) . "." . $imagePath->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $imagePath->storeAs('public/uploads', $imageName);
        $book->image_path = $imageName;
    }

    $book->fill($request->all());

    $book->save();

    return redirect()->route('books.create')
        ->with('success', 'Libro publicado correctamente.');
}
```

Comment: Es que con `$book->fill($request->all())` estas pisando el valor que le habias dado antes a esa propiedad de book `$book->image_path = $imageName;`. Prueba cambiar el orden de esas sentencias

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Muchas gracias, si me funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahi tienes un problema porque justo antes de guardar el modelo, haces:

```php
$book->fill($request->all());
```

El método [`fill()` va a llenar la instancia del modelo](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) que tienes en `$book` con una serie de atributos, los que le pases en el array.
En este caso le estas pasando todos los campos del request `$request->all()`, de los cuales, `image_path` ya habias llenado manualmente cuando hiciste:

```php
$book->image_path = $imageName;
```

Entonces solo quitando ese `fill()`, ya no estarias pisando los valores asignados anteriormente al Modelo.

Si aun asi quieres llenarlo, con otros campos del request,  te sugiero hacer la validacion de todos los campos en `Book::$rules` y asignar el array de campos validados a una variable:

```php
$validated = $request->validate(Book::$rules);
```

Para luego, instanciar el modelo

```php
$book = new Book();
```

Llenarlo solo con campos/datos validados del request

```php
$book->fill($validated);
```

Agregar propiedades que no estuviesen en el request

```php
$book->status = 1;
$book->owner_id = auth()->user()->id;
```

Procesar el archivo y asignar el valor de image_path al Modelo

```php
if ($request->hasFile('image_path')) {
    $file = $request->file('image_path');
    $fileName = Str::slug($request->title) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $file->storeAs('public/uploads', $fileName);
    $book->image_path = $fileName;//$path;
}
```

Finalmente guardar en BD

```php
$book->save();
```